# Mirror modifier mirrors on different axis/axes from the selected one(s)

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I have 2 objects a face and an ear. Mirror modifier works fine for the face. But when I use mirror modifier to duplicate the ear on X axis, it duplicates on Z axis. And when I use mirror modifier on Z axis it mirrors on X axis. How to correct the axis orientation? 
[image: no mirror modifier]
[image: mirror modifier along X]
[image: mirror modifier along Z]

Comment: Have you rotated the ear? If so, try applying the rotation. In object mode `Ctrl` `A` > `R`.

Comment: Thank You. It works fine after rotation. Please write this comment in answer section. I will mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the ear was rotated, you will need to apply the rotation. To do this, in object mode either press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd> or click `Object` > `Apply` > `Rotation`.

See: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)