# How To Have The Mirror Modifier Work Correctly?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

When working on my character model, I wish to mirror half of the character. When I mirror the half of the character, the mirror does not go over symmetrically.

[image]

What are the settings to have the mesh mirror symmetrically?

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file? Preferably through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22987/mirror-modifier-mirrors-on-different-axis-axes-from-the-selected-ones/22989

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1283" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1283/) Thank you for taking a look at it. I only need the body mirrored. If you don't mind telling me how to fix my normal view. (not sure its name) If you hit 5 on the numpad, the view is very "screwy". I was messing with the camera settings without knowing what I was doing and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: See: **[why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)**