# Mirror in the wrong axis

Tags: objects, mirror, origin

First of all, sorry for bad English...

I got a Problem with the mirror modifier... The origin of my object is set to the 3D-curser, which is in the center (0, 0, 0). When I mirror my object, it duplicates to the other side (as it should) but the position is wrong... Why is that?... (The black line is the line I'm mirroring in)

[image]

When you see the objects from the top, It looks like the object is mirrored in a line that isn't even there, as you can see at the photo below, where the yellow line illustrates the unexisting line.

[image]

Any ideas what could cause this mistake?

Comment: Check if there is any unapplied rotation. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22987/mirror-modifier-mirrors-on-different-axis-axes-from-the-selected-ones