# Mirror mod doesn't mirror opposite even when origin set to edges

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I just cant seem to get the mirror modifier to work.  Ive set the origin to the edges and moved the 3d cursor like suggested however when the mod is added it doesn't mirror the object parallel, it just goes in any other direction but opposite on the axis I dont want it to be

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: select the corner edge or the edge where u need mirror and press shift+ctrl+alt+c and select origin to 3d cursor and then add mirror modifier

Comment: Thanks for getting back! Ive tried selecting the edges and setting the 3d cursor to the origin but when I add the modifier the origin s in the right position but it still cant be mirrored on the other side and still passes through :(

Comment: plz attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the mirror modifier work right?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right)

Comment: Your object has unapplied rotation of 45 degrees. If you reset it you will see actual mirroring. Either reset rotation (Alt+R), or apply it (Ctrl+A). In this case applying is the easiest way as it doesn't seem to cause any problems with rotation. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22987/mirror-modifier-mirrors-on-different-axis-axes-from-the-selected-ones for similar case

Comment: @cegaton That duplicate doesn't actually mention applying rotation.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Zak. I was getting so frustrated with it!